# Subscript requires array or pointer type

Tags: c++, string, vector

Hello the aim of this program is to initialize all elements of the vector Rooms to the string Empty, this is my first attempt at tackling vectors and passing by reference as such I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;

 void mainMenu(vector <int> &VectorRooms(), string &EmptyString);

 int main()
{
  vector < int > Rooms(13);
  string str1 = "Empty";

   mainMenu(Rooms, str1);
}

   void mainMenu(vector <int> &VectorRooms(), string &EmptyStrings)
  {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < VectorRooms.size(); i++)
    {
    VectorRooms[i] = EmptyStrings;
    cout << VectorRooms[i] << endl;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
void mainMenu(vector <int> &VectorRooms(), string &EmptyStrings)
```

You mean:

```
void mainMenu(vector <int> &VectorRooms, string &EmptyStrings)
```

Remove those parentheses. With the parentheses there, you're actually declaring `VectorRooms` as a function pointer to a function that returns a `vector <int> &` and takes no parameters, and index `[]` is invalid on a function pointer type. That, of course, isn't your intention